# the will hiding when dropdownlist item has space

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have two `dropdownlist` that work with jquery ajax. when i select item from the first the second dropdown will complete with item that choose from the first dropdownlist. every thing is good when there was `no space between dropdownlit items` but when the text(item in dropdownlist has space all element on the page with hiding) the text is utf8. any idea?

this is my code:

```
 $("#Ddl_Pack_Name").change(function () {//dovomi
      var url = (document.URL)+"&Pname="+$("#Ddl_Pack_Name").val()+"&Sid="+$("#Ddl_Sgroup").val();
      Pid = $("#hidden").val();
      alert(url);
      $("#main").load(url, function () {});
      //alert($(this).val());
      //alert(window.location.pathname);
      //window.location.href = window.location.pathname + "?shahr=" + $(this).val();
 });
 $("#Ddl_Sgroup").change(function () {
      var url = (document.URL)+"&Sid="+$("#Ddl_Sgroup").val();
      alert(url);
      $("#main").load(url, function () { });
 });
```

Comment: Could you create a self contained example that has this behavior? What is the generated url?

Comment: every thing is ok with none space text. i will try  create in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced space with `%20` and problem disappeared (like `churum` and other browsers).